# How to sort this list? python

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
mylist = [
    'Attendance w1-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w15-2 (Responses) - Form responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w5-1 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w7-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w13-2 (Responses) - Form responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w5-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w9-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w4-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w1-1 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w12-2 (Responses) - Form responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w2-1 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w14-2 (Responses) - Form responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w3-1 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w12-1 (Responses) - Form responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w14-1 (Responses) - Form responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w8-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w4-1 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w15-1 (Responses) - Form responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w3-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w6-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w7-1 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w2-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w6-1 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
    'Attendance w11-1 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv'
]
```

How to sort this list based on `wx-x`?

Comment: By using `key` attribute and a suitable lambda function. Do not excpect anyone here to do the job for you if you do not show what you have tried.

Comment: Also, what would the expected output be, and why? Should the numbers be interpreted lexicographically or numerically?

Comment: Sorry. I got this list by reading all file in folder and I'm not good with lamdba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do need the output be:

```
['Attendance w1-1 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w1-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w2-1 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w2-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w3-1 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w3-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w4-1 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w4-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w5-1 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w5-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w6-1 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w6-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w7-1 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w7-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w8-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w9-2 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w11-1 (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w12-1 (Responses) - Form responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w12-2 (Responses) - Form responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w13-2 (Responses) - Form responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w14-1 (Responses) - Form responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w14-2 (Responses) - Form responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w15-1 (Responses) - Form responses 1.csv',
 'Attendance w15-2 (Responses) - Form responses 1.csv']
```

If so:

```
import re
mylist.sort(key=lambda x: float('.'.join(re.findall(' w(\d+)\-(\d+) ', x)[0]
)))
```